# How To Make Tab Bar Buttons Tappable Outside Tab Bar Bounds

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a standard UI Tab Bar controller, with the tabs all added using interface builder. I've used the image inset properties to make the large centre button sit on the edge of the tab bar. However, when I tap on the half that's outside the tab bar bounds it doesn't register anything.

I've currently got no code in place for the tab bar, but I'd like to know how I can have a button like this and make it's taps register even when it's outside the tab bar bounds.

Comment: can you put some images to figure out what is your real intend ?

Comment: I'd just like to be able to tap a UITabBarButton that is positioned slightly outside a tab bar.